# Changed code but still same result, cache?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've commented out some code in `theme-scripts.js` that was causing a problem with my theme but my browser isn't noticing changes?  I added `alert('test')` to the `theme-scripts.js` but the alert didn't show?

I've cleared my browser cache..  I'm following a solution provided by the theme author, it works for everyone but when i change code it isn't recognized.  Is there some other cache i have to clear?

Comment: There is also CTRL+F5 to force a full reload of the content from the server, although in theory this should be no different from clearing the cache. What exactly is the code? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Add a random timestamp to the file ending of the script file, just to make sure. E.g. `.js?12345`

Comment: If you control-refresh, is the issue still the same ?

Comment: which method are you using to include the js file??

Comment: As Rory said press CTRL + F5 sometimes u need to do this

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you installed WordPress, sometimes there are caching plugins pre-installed. For example with the auto-installer I use WP Super Cache comes pre-installed (I had a few headaches before I realised that). This could be stopping your files from refreshing straight away.

Check the plugins list in the backend and see if there are any pre-installed caching plugins that might be causing this. If there are then there should be a way within the plugin to clear or disable the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You 100% that you're editing the code to the correct theme? In FTP should be wp-contents/themes/Your Custom Theme/js/script-to-change.js

only ask as I fell into this trap editing twentyfourteen theme files rather than custom ones....